# email shows html tags it`s not appear in html format

Tags: php, email

I am sending email using editor but it`s also send the html tags and i want to show only html view and This is my email attachment code --

```
$file = 'uploads/email_attachments/'.$row['email_image'];
                            $file_size = filesize($file);
                            $handle = fopen($file, "r");
                            $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                            fclose($handle);
                            $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
                            $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
                            $from_name = "Tino Cesar";
                            $from_mail = "info@tino.co.in";
                            $replyto = $row['email'];
                            $message = $row['message'];
                            $header = "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n";
                            $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
                            $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                            $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
                            $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
                            $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
                            $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
                            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
                            $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
                            $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
                            $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
                            $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
                            $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                            $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
                            $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
                            $header .= "--".$uid."--";
                            $mailto =  $row['email'];
                            $subject = $row['subject'];
                            if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
                                echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
                            } else {
                                echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
                            }
```

Comment: Whey do you set the `content-type` mutiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

to

```
$header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

remove this line

```
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

Comment: @sauravgarg please mark this as correct if the code helped  you .